# Jenkins, AWS. EC2 slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a packer to build a AMI using jenkins job. For example im trying to create a abc ami so that it will spinup new slave, when the job is triggered it is searching for agent which is not created.

stage("Packer abc") {
            agent { label "abc" }

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome, can you please provide more of your code? Do you have a build agent with label `abc` set up?